# R: Finding all occurrences of a name

Tags: r

I've been working on this lesson problem and finally got the answer the quiz was looking for. I'm fairly new to R, less than 5 weeks in, but this took me hours to understand. I was tasked with finding all the occurrences of the name Jurgis, Ona, and Chicago from **The Jungle**.

**Issue:** I wasted a lot of time removing the punctuation using gsub but realized later that some elements were two words: "Jurgis read" would condense to "Jurgisread" and would not pick up the count. Then there were the "Jurgis's"condensing to "Jurgiss", etc for Ona and the city Chicago.

**Would like**: Some tips on how to handle these types of files better in the future.

**What I did**: I was given the first two lines of code to start off. I split elements using the spaces they came with. Then I selected what punctuation I wanted to remove. Once I removed,what I thought, would be all the common ones and replace them with spaces, split the elements again. Finally, I table() and forced all the words to be capital case.

```
 theJungle <- readLines("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/140/140.txt")
 theJungleList <- unlist(strsplit(theJungle[47:13872], " "))

splitJungle1<-unlist(strsplit(theJungleList, "[[:space:]]", fixed = FALSE, 
perl = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE))

remPunctuation<-gsub("-|'|,|:|;|\\.|\\*|\\(|\"|!|\\?"," ",splitJungle1)

splitJungle2<-unlist(strsplit(remPunctuation, "[[:space:]]", fixed = FALSE, perl 
= FALSE, useBytes = FALSE))

table(toupper(splitJungle2)=="JURGIS")
table(toupper(splitJungle2)=="ONA")
table(toupper(splitJungle2)=="CHICAGO")
```

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7srzn.png)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this was for a class, you were probably supposed to use certain techniques. If you are just interested generally in text analysis in R, you might consider using tidy data principles and the tidytext package. Looking for word frequencies is a [pretty quick thing to do](http://tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html) in this mode of working.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)

theJungle <- readLines("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/140/140.txt")
jungle_df <- data_frame(text = theJungle) %>%
    unnest_tokens(word, text)
```

What are the most common words in the text?

```r
jungle_df %>%
    count(word, sort = TRUE)

#> # A tibble: 10,349 × 2
#>     word     n
#>    <chr> <int>
#> 1    the  9114
#> 2    and  7350
#> 3     of  4484
#> 4     to  4270
#> 5      a  4217
#> 6     he  3312
#> 7    was  3056
#> 8     in  2570
#> 9     it  2318
#> 10   had  2234
#> # ... with 10,339 more rows
```

How often do you see the specific names you were looking for?

```r
jungle_df %>%
    count(word) %>%
    filter(str_detect(word, "^jurgis|^ona|^chicago"))

#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>        word     n
#>       <chr> <int>
#> 1   chicago    68
#> 2 chicago's     4
#> 3    jurgis  1098
#> 4  jurgis's    19
#> 5       ona   200
#> 6     ona's    25
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I am interested for later on in the road but yes it was for class. The overarching theme for the week was string manipulation so we have yet to use tidytext but this is a handy package to know.

Comment: great answer - great simple use of "count"!